# Open csv file at a certain line in Python

Tags: python, csv

I want to use python to open a csv file at a certain line.
Not read it in python but open it with Microsoft spreadsheets or WPS.

Answer (score 1):

this code should help you. You just need to specify the file path and the line number in the code given.

```
import subprocess

filename = "example.csv"
line_number = 10
command = f'"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\EXCEL.EXE" /e /r "{filename}"'

subprocess.Popen([command, f'/select,A{line_number}'])
```

Alternativly you can use args to make something like this: `python3 main.py <filename> <line>`. If you need that, please comment. I hope I could help you.

Comment: I have an error  : PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied . Even thought I run Python as admin.

Comment: That's very weird. Have you tried changing the file path in the code I provided? May that causes the error.

Comment: the path is correct . It leads directly to EXEL.exe .Did you try the code in your pc , I think I don't have he rights to open EXCEL.exe